# LibCURL in kernel

Tags: libcurl, freebsd, kernel-module

I wanted to know if there is any library which does the job of libCURL in FreeBSD kernel. I know libCURL is a user-space library but was looking for something similar in kernel. Porting is one option but i think it surely will not be a straight forward thing.

Any leads on the above query would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're attempting here? Generally HTTP requests and the like belong in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. HTTP is not implemented in kernels by ordinary operating systems, neither clients nor servers. Even though there were once [experiments with a http server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUX_web_server) in the Linux kernel..